# Find difference between two objects in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tow object and I need to find differences between this array.

in this array anything not be added or removed but maybe change the value of fields.

I need to send to server changed data not all data for this reason I need to find changed data.

now I use this code to find and send data in the server but I think is not good way to doing this work :

```
    dataSource: DefaultScoreCoinDataSource;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataSourceInit();
     }



    dataSourceInit(): void {
        this.dataSource = new DefaultScoreCoinDataSource(this.defaultScorService);
        this.dataSource.loadDefaultScoreCoins(1, this.pageSize, this.filters);
    }

editAll(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    const items = this.dataSource['defualtScoreSubject'].value;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.dataSource['defualtScoreSubject'].value.length; i++) {
        const item = items[i];
        if (typeof (item['coinValue']) === 'string' || typeof (item['scoreValue']) === 'string') {
            let model = {} as EdiltListModel;
            model.id = item['id'];
            model.coinValue = parseInt(item['coinValue'], null);
            model.scoreValue = parseInt(item['scoreValue'], null);

            this.editListModel.push(model);
        }
    }
}
```

this `this.dataSource['defualtScoreSubject'].value` give me the list of array .

now anybody can help me fo find the best way to find the changed (`edited`) data ???

Comment: please add your sample objects to the question

Comment: @JoelJoseph i edit the question

Comment: You could use lodash xor, xorWith or xorBy (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#xorWith)

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm i can use the `diff` for this solution ?